# Need help to make a function out of a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use the the query below for each country. How do I make a function which will generate the average for each country that is passed to it ?

```
-- pepsi drink database
select avg(monthly_sales)
from world_sales
where product name like '%juice%'
and country = 'germany' -- this can be japan, usa, china etc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
create function dbo.getAverageMonthlySaleForCountry(@country varchar(100))
returns decimal(20,4)
as
begin
  return (
    select avg(monthly_sales)
    from world_sales
    where product name like '%juice%'
    and country = @country
  )
end
GO
```

Be warned however, that SCALAR functions like this have limited use when it comes to performance (read: it's *exceptionally bad* for performance). Use with care.

Comment: Be sure "product_name" and "country" colums indexed.

Comment: Is there any way to improve the performance, besides indexing of columns ?

Comment: @David - Sure - **don't** use SCALAR functions unless you're sure it won't be called much in the query, say 3 to 5 rows. Kaffee's query shows you a way to do it "for all countries" in an outer query without using a SCALAR function.

Answer (score 2):

It does not answer your direct question, but why not group by country?

```
select avg(monthly_sales), country
from world_sales
where product name like '%juice%' group by country;
```

Comment: Well, that is not what i wanted to do.

Comment: How is it a good point when it returns a different result set than what he originally wanted?

Comment: My thought was that maybe he is iterating over a couple of countries and is calling the function. Then it would be easier to group by country in one call instead of multiple. Just pointing out an alternative.

Comment: Perhaps we have the XY problem here where the OP asks for what he _thinks_ is the solution.